# How to pass width value to custom attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Suppose that I have an `<img>` tag that has a `data-width` and `data-height` attribute set to 0.

How can I get the width and the height of my img, and then pass it to my custom attributes?

Can someone please help me with this. I've been digging for so long.

Here's my code that didn't work:

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: 'move'
});
$("#dropzone").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var canvas = $(this);
        if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('object')) {
            var canvasElement = ui.helper.clone();
            canvasElement.addClass('object');
            canvas.find("div").removeClass('activeElement');
            canvasElement.addClass('activeElement');
            canvasElement.removeClass('draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging');
            var mywidth = canvasElement.find("img").width();
            canvasElement.find("img").data("width",mywidth);
            canvas.append(canvasElement);
            canvasElement.css({
                left: (ui.position.left),
                top: (ui.position.top),
                position: 'absolute',
                zIndex: 2              
            });

            canvasElement.draggable({
             cursor: 'move',
             containment: '#dropzone'
           });
```

Comment: tried $("img").data("width", $(this).width()) ?

Comment: yeah. not working

Comment: Have you tried  `setAttribute("data-width")`?

Comment: @mseifert Whats the syntax?

Comment: For clarity - I assume your img tags do not have explicit attributes for width etc, they are merely inheriting the width of the actual image, correct?

Comment: Cannot reproduce.

Comment: I solved it. Its just the position of my code. I let the element append first before getting its width and height.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what issues you are having getting or setting `.data()`? You should be able to get the `width`, `height` of `img` element using `.attr()` or `DOM` `.naturalWidth`, `.naturalHeight`, then set `.data()` using values retrieved from `attr()`

```
var img = $("img");
var [width, height] = [img.attr("width"), img.attr("height")];
img.data({width:width, height:height});
```

Comment: That might be because of `var [ width, height ] = ....` is a ECMAScript 6 feature called [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) that might not be available in your browser.

Comment: @JqueryNewbie Can you describe "not working"? Does using `var width = img.attr("width"); var height = img.attr("height")` return expected result?

Comment: I tried on chrome and firefox.

I already tried that code. It also didn't work

Comment: @JqueryNewbie What do you mean by "didn't work"? What is `canvasElement`?

Comment: returns 0.

canvasElement is the div that i dropped.

Comment: What returns `0`? Have you tried using `img[0].naturalWidth` and `img[0].naturalHeight`? Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: What does `console.log(!ui.draggable.hasClass('object'))` log at `console`?

Comment: What does `console.log(myWidth, canvasElement.find("img")[0].naturalWidth)` log at `console`?

Comment: @JqueryNewbie Can you share result of `console.log(myWidth, canvasElement.find("img")[0].naturalWidth)` ?

Comment: @JqueryNewbie ... i guess this exactly answers the question :( , in case u  don't want to use ES6 features you can just use var x = $("#img).width() and like. Unless we are missing an important piece of the puzzle i think this is the solution !

Comment: I solved it. Its just the position of my code. I let the element append first before getting its width and height.

Comment: @JqueryNewbie See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Its just the position of my code. I let the element append first before getting its width and height.